# How can I simultaneity run blocks of code with key bindings?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, key-bindings

I am currently learning how to use key bindings. I was toying with the code I wrote, and I noticed when I press two keys (arrow keys), only the last one would run. Should I simply use KeyListener or is there a way to make this work? Since its a game, it would have to be able to run over 4 keys at the same time.

```
package game;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import game.sfx.Screen;
import game.sfx.SpriteSheet;

public class Game implements Runnable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public boolean running = false;
    public int tickCount = 0;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    Screen screen;

    public Game(){
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

        frame = new JFrame(NAME);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW); // key binding here
        ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "r");
        am.put("r", new InputHandler("right", this));
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "l");
        am.put("l", new InputHandler("left", this));    
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "u");
        am.put("u", new InputHandler("up", this));  
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "d");
        am.put("d", new InputHandler("down", this));    

    }


    public void init(){
        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT, new SpriteSheet("res/Untitled.png"));
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {     
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D/60D;

        int frames = 0;
        int ticks = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;

        init();

        while (running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean shouldRender = true;
            while(delta >= 1)
            {
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (shouldRender)
            {
                frames++;
                render();
            }

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000){
                lastTimer += 1000;
                System.out.println(ticks + " ticks, " + frames + " frames");
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick(){
        tickCount++;


    }

    public void render(){


        screen.render(pixels, 0, WIDTH);

        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), null);

        g.dispose();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        new Game().start();     
    }

}

class InputHandler extends AbstractAction {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String key;
    private Game game;


    public InputHandler(String key, Game game) {
        this.key = key;
        this.game = game;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
        switch(key){
        case "right": 
        game.screen.xOffset+=2;
        break;
        case "left": 
        game.screen.xOffset-=2;
        break;
        case "up": 
        game.screen.yOffset+=2;
        break;
        case "down": 
        game.screen.yOffset-=2;
        break;
        }

    }

}
```

This is the code

Comment: Where's your pertinent code? Without this you make your question difficult to answer. Please read the [mcve] link and then try to create and post one of these programs with your question. This is not your complete program or a link but a small separate runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java KeyEvent square movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476685/java-keyevent-square-movement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what I recommend in my [linked to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19477105/522444):

- Create a game loop using a Swing Timer
- Create an enum called Direction that has UP, DOWN, LEFT, and RIGHT items
- And that also has int vector fields that indicate actual direction
- Create a `HashMap<Direction, Boolean>` that is changed when an arrow key is pressed
- Have the game loop pole this  map, and alter direction depending on which direction is mapped to Boolean.TRUE.
- Set up your Key Bindings to simply change the state of the HashMap, and that's it.

Comment: I looked at your answer. When I run the code, the square successfully go on the diagonal when up/down and left/right are pressed. However, how come the square does not go to the left when I press up, down and left? Wouldn't the up/down cancel and simply go to the left? This is not an issue, I just seek to understand.

Comment: @Ilann: it goes to the left when I press up/down/left together.

Comment: @Ilann: my own code from the link to my previous answer.

Comment: Well, I tried again. I don't know why it's different.

Comment: As soon as two keys are pressed, the other keys become unresponsive.

Comment: Arrows on the numpad work just like you said. I guess its just my computer.

Comment: I am not familiar with enums. How is   private Direction(int incrX, int incrY) {
      this.incrX = incrX;
      this.incrY = incrY;
   } called?

Comment: @Ilann: All enums use private constructors, and that's because you never directly call this constructor, but rather it's called by the enum itself, and only once. Note that the enum declarations all carry parameters that match the private constructor. You will want to read up on these very useful and core Java concepts.

Answer (score 2):

> and I noticed when I press two keys (arrow keys), only the last one would run

Because only events are generated for the last key pressed

> Should I simply use KeyListener

This is true whether you use a KeyListener or KeyBindings. Its the OS that generates the event.

> Since its a game, it would have to be able to run over 4 keys at the same time.

So the solution is to track each key as it is pressed/released

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). The `KeyboardAnimation` example shows how this can be done with KeyBindings.