# Call method given string for it

Tags: java, string, function, call

Say I have a list of methods named fooUp, fooDown, fooLeft, fooRight

Is there a way I can make some sort of code in java that can call a method given a string of the method name?

Example:

```
move(String str)
{
    call("foo" + str)
}

fooUp()
{
}

fooDown()
{
}

fooLeft()
{
}

fooRight()
{
}
mainFunction()
{
    move("Left")
}
```

This is just sample code but I was thinking of doing something like this to make one method call rather than having the code within the method be repeated. Basically less lines of / cleaner code.

Comment: "java reflections" is what you are looking for.

Comment: You could use a switch statement instead, and call a different method for each case.

Comment: Your question sounds like it may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code" when the real solution is to use a different approach entirely. Yes, you could do this with reflection, and no, this is not the best way to solve these types of problems. Likely a better solution is around the corner by re-factoring your program.

Comment: For instance, consider looking at using the [Command Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) combined with enums for a much more robust solution.

Comment: ... and in fact I've done something similar to this for a Swing GUI that used an enum called `Direction` to help decide where to move a sprite based on key press. You can find the code and the answer here: [Java KeyEvent square movement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19477105/522444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use reflection. I'll leave it to you to look into reflection and how to use it, but your code will look something like this:

```
YourClass.class.getMethod(yourObject, yourMethodString, yourArgumentTypes).execute(yourArguments);
```

It doesn't make for pretty code and most of the time, it's best to avoid it at as much as possible. A better solution for the example provided might be to use the string in a switch statement to determine which method to call.