# How can I set up my keybinds in such a way that the character does not pause between inputs?

Tags: java, swing, game-development, key-bindings

I'm attempting to make a simple bullet hell game and am struggling to make smooth movement mechanics for the character. Here is my current code:

```
package bullethell;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GameDisplay extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2586882806098087146L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private GameObject player;
    
    int xDirection = 0;
    int yDirection = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GameDisplay frame = new GameDisplay();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public GameDisplay() throws IOException {
        setUndecorated(true);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        setMovementKeys();
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0, 
                  0, 
                  (int) 500, 
                  (int) 500);
        
        Image sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("Sprites/Player.png"));
        player = new GameObject(sprite);
        player.setBounds(0, 0, sprite.getWidth(null), sprite.getHeight(null));
        contentPane.add(player);
    }

    private void setMovementKeys() {
        
        InputMap in = contentPane.getInputMap();
        ActionMap out = contentPane.getActionMap();
        
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "w-pressed");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "w-released");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "a-pressed");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "a-released");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "s-pressed");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "s-released");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "d-pressed");
        in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "d-released");
        
        out.put("w-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(0,-10));
        out.put("w-released", new MovementKeyAction(0,0));
        out.put("a-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(-10,0));
        out.put("a-released", new MovementKeyAction(0,0));
        out.put ("s-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(0,10));
        out.put("s-released", new MovementKeyAction(0,0));
        out.put ("d-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(10,0));
        out.put("d-released", new MovementKeyAction(0,0));
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player.setLocation(player.getX() + xDirection, player.getY() + yDirection);
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private class MovementKeyAction extends AbstractAction {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3671863065039719595L;
        public int x, y;
        
        public MovementKeyAction(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            xDirection = x;
            yDirection = y;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

What I am struggling with is modifying this so that there is no delay between inputs of different directions. Here is a gif of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy6mT.gif

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An example of this is in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476685/java-keyevent-square-movement). One suggestion regarding your code: don't use a Swing Timer delay of `1` as it is simply not realistic. Perhaps 12 or more is more doable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the event state (press/release) directly, instead, update a "direction" state which can include both vertical and horizontal directions simultaneously and then use the "game loop" (ie the `Timer`) to make determinations about what to do based on that state.

The problem you're trying to solve is a OS based one, there is a delay between the first and repeating key events, so, instead, you get the first key event and update some kind of state, this then allows the `Timer` to manage that state

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GamePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
//
//    public class GameDisplay extends JFrame {
//
//        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2586882806098087146L;
//        private JPanel contentPane;
//        private Shape player;
//
//        int xDirection = 0;
//        int yDirection = 0;
//
//        public GameDisplay() throws IOException {
//            setUndecorated(true);
//            contentPane = new JPanel() {
//                @Override
//                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
//                    return new Dimension(500, 500);
//                }
//            };
//            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
//            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
//            setContentPane(contentPane);
//
//            setMovementKeys();
//
//            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//
//            player = new Re
//            
//            player.setBounds(0, 0, sprite.getWidth(null), sprite.getHeight(null));
//            contentPane.add(player);
//        }
//    }

    protected class GamePane extends JPanel {
        public enum Direction {
            UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
        }

        private Set<Direction> directions = new TreeSet<>();
        private Player player = new Player();

        public GamePane() {
            setLayout(null);
            player.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);
            add(player);
            setMovementKeys();
            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int x = player.getX();
                    int y = player.getY();
                    if (directions.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                        y -= 1;
                    } else if (directions.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                        y += 1;
                    }
                    if (directions.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                        x -= 1;
                    } else if (directions.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                        x += 1;
                    }

                    if (y < 0) {
                        y = 0;
                    } else if (y + player.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                        y = getHeight() - player.getHeight();
                    }
                    if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                    } else if (x + player.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - player.getWidth();
                    }

                    player.setLocation(x, y);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        private void setMovementKeys() {
            InputMap in = getInputMap();
            ActionMap out = getActionMap();

            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "w-pressed");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "w-released");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "a-pressed");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "a-released");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "s-pressed");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "s-released");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "d-pressed");
            in.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "d-released");

            out.put("w-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.UP, true));
            out.put("w-released", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.UP, false));
            out.put("a-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.LEFT, true));
            out.put("a-released", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.LEFT, false));
            out.put("s-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.DOWN, true));
            out.put("s-released", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.DOWN, false));
            out.put("d-pressed", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.RIGHT, true));
            out.put("d-released", new MovementKeyAction(Direction.RIGHT, false));
        }

        protected void didActivate(Direction direction) {
            directions.add(direction);
        }

        protected void didDeactivate(Direction direction) {
            directions.remove(direction);
        }

        private class MovementKeyAction extends AbstractAction {

            private Direction direction;
            private boolean active;

            public MovementKeyAction(Direction direction, boolean active) {
                this.direction = direction;
                this.active = active;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(direction + "/" + active);
                if (active) {
                    didActivate(direction);
                } else {
                    didDeactivate(direction);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    protected class Player extends JComponent {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```